# Mysql place data on multiple rows into one row based on date

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following data in a MYSQL table.

| ID | NAME | PHONENO | EMAIL | TMDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | Sarah | 0884100300 |  | 1-Jan-21 |
| 1234 | Sarah | 0881500900 |  | 5-Mar-21 |
| 1234 | Sarah |  | Sarah@gmail.com | 10-Mar-21 |
| 0001 | James | 09991234567 |  | 31-Dec-20 |
| 0001 | James |  | james@yahoo.com | 31-Dec-20 |

The table contain email and phone numbers for customers. If the phonenumber or email is updated, the data is recorded on a new row. The TMDate column shows when the record was collected.

I want the final output to be as follows:

| ID | NAME | PHONENO | EMAIL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | Sarah | 0881500900 | example@gmail.com |
| 0001 | James | 09991234567 | james@yahoo.com |

My approach was to first pull the phone numbers based on max data using script below and then pull the emails using a script with similar logic and then do inner join of the two

```
 SELECT t1.id,
   t1.name
   t2.PHONENO,
   t2.max_date
 FROM phoneemail t1
  INNER JOIN
   (SELECT id,PHONENO, MAX(TMDATE) as max_date FROM phoneemail group by id,phoneno where t1.phoneno 
 is not null) t2
   ON t1.id = t2.id
```

My approach is not working as I am still getting duplicate records

Comment: Please only tag the relevant RDBMS

Comment: What you're missing is a [group by](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The columns `PHONENO` and `EMAIL` my have been updated in different dates, so getting the latest date for each ID will not help.

If your version of MySql is 8.0+ you can do it with `FIRST_VALUE()` window function, which does not support `IGNORE NULLS`, so conditional sorting is also needed:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ID, NAME,
       FIRST_VALUE(PHONENO) OVER (PARTITION BY ID, NAME ORDER BY PHONENO IS NULL, TMDate DESC) PHONENO,
       FIRST_VALUE(EMAIL) OVER (PARTITION BY ID, NAME ORDER BY EMAIL IS NULL, TMDate DESC) EMAIL
FROM phoneemail
```

For prior versions you need 2 correlated subqueries:

```
SELECT DISTINCT p1.ID, p1.NAME,
  (SELECT p2.PHONENO FROM phoneemail p2 
   WHERE (p2.ID, p2.NAME) = (p1.ID, p1.NAME) AND p2.PHONENO IS NOT NULL 
   ORDER BY TMDate DESC LIMIT 1) PHONENO,
  (SELECT p3.EMAIL FROM phoneemail p3 
   WHERE (p3.ID, p3.NAME) = (p1.ID, p1.NAME) AND p3.EMAIL IS NOT NULL 
   ORDER BY TMDate DESC LIMIT 1) EMAIL 
FROM phoneemail p1
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a0366d9b577a8f982d0f6a2a30e6dbc5).
Results:

| ID | NAME | PHONENO | EMAIL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | Sarah | 0881500900 | Sarah@gmail.com |
| 0001 | James | 09991234567 | james@yahoo.com |

Answer (score 1):

MySQL does not have a "first" or "last" aggregation function.  So, one method is to use window functions:

```
select distinct id, name,
       first_value(phone ignore nulls) over (partition by id order by tmdate desc) as phone,
       first_value(email ignore nulls) over (partition by id order by tmdate desc) as email
from (select distinct id, name from t) t;
```

Happily, `first_value()` has the `ignore nulls` option.